# In IntelliJ, how to automatically change getter/setter from static to non-static

Tags: java, static, setter, getter

In IntelliJ, when changing a variable declaration from static to non-static, is there a way to automatically change its getter and setter's declaration from static to non-static?

Comment: I can't find any, and I just spent the last several minutes trying...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done automatically. When you call a non-static member of a class, you need a reference to the object.

```
something = MyClass.getSomething():
```

Should be changed to

```
something = instanceOfMyClass.getSomething();
```

It's hard to guess which variable must be put in place of `instanceOfMyClass`.